# How to transfer from one ether wallet to another using smartcontract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, contract-design, tokens

I try to transfer ethers from one account to another using my smart contract but the contract doesn't allow me with following functions :

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success)            /* A contract attempts to get the coins */ 
        {
            if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) 
            {
                throw;                                              // Check if the sender has enough
            }                 
            if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) 
            {
                throw;                                              // Check for overflows
            }  
            if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) 
            {
                throw;                                              // Check allowance
            }   
            balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                             // Subtract from the sender
            balanceOf[_to] += _value;                               // Add the same to the recipient
            allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
            Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
        }
function sell(uint256 TokensAmount) afterDeadline
        {

            uint256 amount = TokensAmount;
            if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < amount ) 
            {
                throw;                                              // checks if the sender has enough to sell
            }        
            uint256 revenue = amount * sellPrice;
            balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;                        // subtracts the amount from seller's balance
            balanceOf[Killer] += amount;                            // adds the amount to owner's balance
            KilledTokens[msg.sender] += amount;
            KilledTillNow += amount;
            address _to = msg.sender;
            address _from = owner;
            uint256 _value = revenue;

            if (!msg.sender.send(revenue)) 
            {                                                       // sends ether to the seller: it's important
                throw;                                              // to do this last to prevent recursion attacks
            } 
            else 
            {  
                transferFrom(_from, _to, _value)
                Transfer(msg.sender, Killer, amount);               // executes an event reflecting on the change
                return;                                             // ends function and returns
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem appears to be in the approach.

You're trying to move eth from wallets the contract doesn't control. A contract can do most things a person can but not more. If can't, for example, spend someone else's money.

Think about this way:

- Sender -> Contract
- Contract -> Receiver (using money it received).

---

```
function pay(address receiver) payable returns(bool success) {
  // uint paid = msg.value
  balance[msg.sender] += paid;
  return true;
}

function claim() returns(bool success) {
  if(balance[msg.sender]==0) throw;
  uint amount = balance[msg.sender];
  msg.sender.transfer(amount);
  return true;
}
```

Hope it helps.